# Expectation of the absolut value of the determinant of a random matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics, determinant

Let $A$ be a random matrix of size $m\times m$ with integer entries $-n\ldots n$. Each value should have the same
 probability. What is the expectation of the random variable

$$X := |\det A|$$

Can the variance of $X$ also be calculated ?

Comment: Do you seriously think this has a simple answer?

Comment: Since the expectation is a linear function, I have some hope that the problem is not too difficult. But it is clear that the expectation of absolut values is not so easy to calculate.

Comment: The second sentence of your comment should suffice to destroy the "hope" expressed in the first sentence.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/18.338/www/Acta05rmt.pdf

Comment: @Count: That's a long document. Can you point us to the relevant part, and maybe briefly summarize what's to be found there?

Comment: I was not able to discover anything useful for this problem in that paper. But I learned there is a theory of random matrices. I found [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851781/expected-value-of-a-determinant) more related.